# bash tab auto-complete is too slow

Tags: bash, autocomplete

my pc has trouble doing tab auto-completion.

Say, I want to find a file whose name starts from 'a'. Then, I push the tab button like this.

```
$ ls a<tab>
```

Then, it is stuck like 2~3 seconds:( It bothers so much..

Plus, there's a one thing that maybe you should know.

Say agian, I want to find a file whose name starts from 'a'.

If there is only one file whose name starts from `a` in pwd, it works very well. I mean, there's no delay at all.

But if there's more than one file, it starts being stuck.

And, I followed https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/185960 method to investigate this. But, when I push the tab button after `set -x`, it is stuck at the first place. I mean,

```sh
$ set -x
$ ls a<tab>
# got stuck like 2~3 second
output of `set -x`
```

Here's my pc information.

```sh
$ uname -a
Linux seongwoo 5.4.0-72-generic #80~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 12 23:26:25 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Although I'm using oh-my-zsh, it has same trouble when I `exec /bin/bash`.

Comment: My guess : You have one or many network paths (nsfd?)  in your PATH environment variable. _Autocomplete_ tries to search trough all  provided path in `$PATH`, and some of them aren't mounted or very slow. It could be also paths from missing/unavailable external storage devices, or a faulting/failing storage device, check your system log.

Comment: @Zilog80 Thank you for your comment. This is my `$PATH`. `/home/seongwoo/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`. As you said, actually, I doubt about the `$PATH` but are they normally mounted from same device?(in this case ssd). I'll check more detail..

Comment: Well.. Even if I `unset PATH`, tab command causes freeze.. Why on earth..

Comment: So it is not the PATH... I guess you're using a local *nix on your PC, not one running in a VM ?

Comment: Can you provide us the output of `ldd /bin/bash` and `set | grep '^LD'` ? Also, try to set PATH with '/bin:/usr/bin' and launch a new bash and test autocompletion.

Comment: @Zilog80
```
$ ldd /bin/bash
 linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd985ed000)
 libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f247cc15000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f247ca11000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f247c620000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f247d159000)
```
And, `set | grep '^LD'` has no output.

Comment: @Zilog80 And, I'm sorry but I have no idea about `*nix`. I'm not using VM.

Comment: @Zilog80 Also, setting PATH to '/bin:/usr/bin' didn't work:(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231926/discussion-between-zilog80-and-chae-seongwoo).

Answer (score -2):

ran in a similar problem.
Either bash TAB-completion and ls command where very slow. After considering multiple solutions that seemed difficult to apply, I found this solution :

```
sudo updatedb
```

This solution is published on the blog https://blog.jaimyn.dev/possible-fix-really-slow-tab-auto-completion-ubuntu-bash/

It seems to update the auto completion database.

Comment: 'updatedb' is not the "auto completion database", 'updatedb' is a command used to update the mlocate.db database for the system 'locate' command. I doubt it has any relation to the shell autocomplete.